# Automatic type constructor for a type synonym

Tags: haskell

I have a type called `Vec2F` and I can use it like this `Vec2F 0.0 0.0`. But I want to make my own type

`type Direction = Vec2F`

But then I can't do `Direction 0.0 0.0` and I have to define a new function which is a little bit cumbersome.

`direction :: Float -> Float -> Vec2F

direction = Vec2F`

What alternatives do I have?

Comment: Is that really cumbersome? One option is `newtype Direction = Direction Vec2F`. You'd then create `Direction`s like `Direction (Vec2F 0.0 0.0)`. Note that now `Direction` and `Vec2F` are distinct types (unlike with `type Direction = Vec2F` where the two are synonymous).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I have a type called `Vec2F` and I can use it like this `Vec2F 0.0 0.0`

No you cannot.

What you actually have is a data definition

```
data Vec2F = Vec2F Double Double
```

It's the second `Vec2f` you can use in expressions. These two occurrences of `Vec2F` are invisible to each other. They live in separate namespaces. One is a type constructor and the other is a *data constructor*.

You can have definitions like

```
data Foo = Bar Double
data Bar = Foo Float
```

and the language will swallow it (as opposed to the human reader).

When you define a type synonym, it only becomes a synonym for the type (constructor). It knows nothing about the data constructor.

There's no way to define a data constructor synonym in standard Haskell. You probably can use [view patterns](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/ViewPatterns) `[-XViewPatterns]` to a similar effect. I have not tried them.

Answer (score 2):

One option is

```
newtype Direction = Direction Vec2F
```

You'd then create `Direction`s like `Direction (Vec2F 0.0 0.0)`. Note that now `Direction` and `Vec2F` are distinct types, whereas they would be synonymous if you had used `type Direction = Vec2F`.